# Symmetric Set recursive functions

Tags: recursion

What do you call a function that takes an ordered set S of reals to a real and has the property that f(S) = f({f({S-{x}),x}) for all x in S? Ex summing a set of numbers. You can take out one number sum the rest then sum the partial sum with the number that was removed to get the same result.